# Does my code is not correctly implementing google chromecast button and ability to stream?

Tags: ios, swift, chromecast

I have implemented google chrome cast and added the button programmatically, but the device is not showing the button and ability to stream. Does my code have written not correctly ??

I have tried this guide https://dev.to/lawgimenez/implement-chromecast-on-ios-using-swift-4dd4 and my button not showing me.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import QuickLook
import GoogleMobileAds
import GoogleCast

class MediaViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate, QLPreviewControllerDelegate, QLPreviewControllerDataSource,     GADInterstitialDelegate, GCKSessionManagerListener, GCKRequestDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var bannerView: DFPBannerView!
@IBOutlet weak var mediaTableView: UITableView!
private var castButton: GCKUICastButton!

var interstitial: GADInterstitial!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    castButton = GCKUICastButton(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(24), height: CGFloat(24)))
    // Overwrite the UIAppearance theme in the AppDelegate.
    castButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: castButton)
}
```

This is my Appdelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import AVFoundation
import GoogleCast

let themeColor = UIColor(red: 0.01, green: 0.41, blue: 0.22, alpha: 1.0)

let kPrefPreloadTime = "preload_time_sec"
let kPrefEnableAnalyticsLogging = "enable_analytics_logging"
let kPrefAppVersion = "app_version"
let kPrefSDKVersion = "sdk_version"
let kPrefEnableMediaNotifications = "enable_media_notifications"

let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GCKLoggerDelegate {

let kReceiverAppID = "6D744F12"
fileprivate var enableSDKLogging = true
fileprivate var mediaNotificationsEnabled = false
fileprivate var firstUserDefaultsSync = false
fileprivate var useCastContainerViewController = false
let kDebugLoggingEnabled = true

var window: UIWindow?
var isCastControlBarsEnabled: Bool!

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let criteria = GCKDiscoveryCriteria(applicationID: kReceiverAppID)
    let options = GCKCastOptions(discoveryCriteria: criteria)
    options.physicalVolumeButtonsWillControlDeviceVolume = true
    GCKCastContext.setSharedInstanceWith(options)

    // Enable logger.
    let logFilter = GCKLoggerFilter()
    logFilter.minimumLevel = .verbose
    GCKLogger.sharedInstance().filter = logFilter
    GCKLogger.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    // MARK - GCKLoggerDelegate

    func logMessage(_ message: String, at level: GCKLoggerLevel, fromFunction function: String, location: String) {
        if (kDebugLoggingEnabled) {
            // Send SDK's log messages directly to the console.
            print("\(location): \(function) - \(message)")

        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Did you register your cast device in the Google Cast Developer Console? Did you add your app id to the source code?

Comment: @AshokPolu sure, I have bith register and added the app to the source code

Comment: May this link helps you https://plus.google.com/113324655656989783855/posts/9ARfwGbKZ9W

Comment: @AshokPolu it all the same problem as mine, but all I need is the ability to work with the lates version of SDK which is not working (((

Comment: Are you sure your device and Chromecast are at the same network? Also are you sure Chromecast is on?

Comment: Yes the network is the same (((

Comment: Your code looks fine. I guess you also implemented the first part that is in `AppDelegate` and is for discovery. Can you also post this part? Also what is the colour of your navigation bar - any chance it's white? Have you implemented `logMessage` of `GCKLoggerDelegate`. If yes - do you see any logs from Chromecast?

Comment: @surToTheW Yeah, here I added my app delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I am also making a cast app. I ran into the same thing, here is what worked for me. As it turned out, you need to tell the navigation to turn on.

```
// initiates the navigation bar to place the chrome icon
    titleView = navigationItem.titleView
    rootTitleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo_castvideos.png"))
    castButton = GCKUICastButton(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0),
                                               width: CGFloat(24), height: CGFloat(24)))
  castButton.isHidden = false
    castButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
    self.setNavigationBar()
    NSObject.setAccessibilityLabel("true")
```